# AngularJS dropdown validation

Tags: angularjs

Good Day,

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown in AngularJS.  The dropdown is populating, but what I'm trying to  is:

If the user submits the button and the dropdown is *not* selected, then I want an error message to appear right below the dropdown.  I'm pretty sure I'm using ng-show correctly, and console.log is telling me in the controller that the dropdown isn't selected, but I can't see my text.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SampleController">
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-area"> 
    <form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm(myForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="service_id" class="form-control"
                ng-model="ServiceID" 
                ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in services"
                required> 
            <option value="">Select Service</option>
            <div class="red" ng-show="myForm.service_id.$invalid && serviceNotSelected">You must select a service.</div>                                
        </select> 
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my controller:

```
sample.controller('SampleController', ['$scope', '$location',
    function ($scope, $location) {

        $scope.services = [
            { ServiceID: 1, ServiceName: 'Service1' },
            { ServiceID: 2, ServiceName: 'Service2' },
            { ServiceID: 3, ServiceName: 'Service3' }
        ];

        $scope.serviceNotSelected = false;

        $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {

            if ($scope.ServiceID === "" || $scope.ServiceID === undefined) {
                console.log('Not Selected:  ' + $scope.ServiceID);
                $scope.serviceNotSelected = true;       
            } else {
                console.log('Selected: ' + $scope.ServiceID);
            }

            console.log('isValid is:  ' + isValid);


            // check to make sure the form is completely valid
            if (isValid) {
                alert('our form is amazing');
            }
        };

    }
]);
```

My ng-show is not working.  Can anyone tell me why?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you added you error div inside select. Adding div outside the select should fix the issue

```
    <select name="service_id" class="form-control"
            ng-model="ServiceID" 
            ng-options="service.ServiceID as service.ServiceName for service in services"
            required> 
        <option value="">Select Service</option>                              
    </select> 

   <div class="red" ng-show="myForm.service_id.$invalid && serviceNotSelected">You must select a service.</div>
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!  I moved it out of the select and it worked.  I didn't even notice that until you pointed it out

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your form so that it only submits if it's valid:

```
<form role="form" name="myForm" ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submitForm()">
```

Remove that `notSelected` thing which is useless. myForm.$submitted will only be true once you try to submit your form (even if it fails due to validation)

```
<div class="red" ng-show="myForm.service_id.$invalid && myForm.$submitted">You must select a service.</div>
```

Remove that stuff from your submit method:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
  //if you are here, your form is valid.
};
```

This should work.

Comment: that didn't work out the way I hoped,  The validation does fire off, but instead of seeing the "You must select a service", it shows a tooltip saying you must select an item.