# Using AngularJS: How can I add validation to reject a specified value from dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am very new to AngularJS and have been tasked with amending the validation on a dropdown. The dropdown renders only when specific values (countries) are selected from a different dropdown. The dropdown I am working is populated with a list of states for the selected country, the names of which are obtained from a json object on the server.

The options in the states dropdown appear to be given numeric values (these are not in the json object). The first option is `please select` and has a value of `0`. This one seems to be selected automatically. So, I need this to be rejected by validation.

I tried adding `required` to the `<select>` but that has not had the desired effect - probably because an option *is* selected.

I also tried [AngularJS dropdown validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599035/angularjs-dropdown-validation) but it didn't work for me.

Here is the Angular code

```
<div class="form-group state-surround"
     ng-class="{'has-error': (newAddressForm.state.$dirty || isPageSubmitted) && newAddressForm.state.$error.required}"
     ng-if="(address.countryCode == 'CA' || address.countryCode == 'IN' || address.countryCode == 'US')">
  <label for="address-primary-input-state">State</label>
  <select required name="state" id="address-primary-input-state" size="1" 
          class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="address.stateCode"
          ng-options="s.code as s.name for s in states[address.countryCode]">
  </select>
</div>
```

And here is the json object which populates the `<select>` with the options

```
var states = {
    CA: [
      { code: "", name: "Please select" },{ code: "AB", name: "Alberta" },{ code: "BC", name: "British Columbia" },{ code: "MB", name: "Manitoba" },{ code: "NB", name: "New Brunswick" },{ code: "NL", name: "Newfoundland and Labrador" },{ code: "NS", name: "Nova Scotia" },{ code: "NT", name: "Northwest Territories" },{ code: "NU", name: "Nunavut" },
      { code: "ON", name: "Ontario" },{ code: "PE", name: "Prince Edward Island" },{ code: "QC", name: "Quebec" },{ code: "SK", name: "Saskatchewan" }, { code: "YT", name: "Yukon" }
    ],.....
```

As mentioned earlier, the dropdowns are populated exactly as expected. What I need help with is how to have angular reject the following selected option:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected" label="Please select">Please select</option>
```

Comment: add the value as "" instead of "0" for the options and validate form using $valid

Comment: Thanks @AmstelD'Almeida, but the value is auto generated from somewhere. As mentioned in the question, all the options get a numeric value from somewhere. being very new to Angular, I do no know how

Comment: Add trackby to your ng-options.

Comment: Will the 'Please select' option be at the first place always?

Comment: @PratyushSharma yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single hard-coded `<option>` element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the `<select>` element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

Remove the `Please select` entry from the `ng-options` array and add it to the template as a disabled `<option>`. Then be sure to initialize the model value to `null`.

For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-options Directive API Reference - Overview](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#overview)

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    //$scope.address = { countryCode: 'CA', stateCode: "" };
    $scope.address = { countryCode: 'CA', stateCode: null };
    
    $scope.states = {
      CA: [
        // { code: "", name: "Please select" },
        { code: "AB", name: "Alberta" },
        { code: "BC", name: "British Columbia" },
        { code: "MB", name: "Manitoba" },{ code: "NB", name: "New Brunswick" },
        { code: "NL", name: "Newfoundland and Labrador" },
        { code: "NS", name: "Nova Scotia" },
        { code: "NT", name: "Northwest Territories" },
        { code: "NU", name: "Nunavut" },{ code: "ON", name: "Ontario" },
        { code: "PE", name: "Prince Edward Island" },
        { code: "QC", name: "Quebec" },{ code: "SK", name: "Saskatchewan" },
        { code: "YT", name: "Yukon" }
      ]
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div class="form-group state-surround" ng-class="{'has-error': (newAddressForm.state.$dirty || isPageSubmitted) && newAddressForm.state.$error.required}" ng-if="(address.countryCode == 'CA' || address.countryCode == 'IN' || address.countryCode == 'US')">
    <label for="address-primary-input-state">State</label>
    <select required name="state" id="address-primary-input-state" size="1"
            class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="address.stateCode"
            ng-options="s.code as s.name for s in states[address.countryCode]">
       <option value="" disabled>Please select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of validating it afterwards, you can disable it so it can't be selected, with `disable when !s.code` (when `code` property is evaluated to false in this case). Additionnally, `address.stateCode` default can be set to `''` so that this options is selected by default:

```js
angular.module('selectExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    
    $scope.address = { countryCode: 'CA', stateCode: '' };
    
    $scope.states = {
      CA: [
        { code: "", name: "Please select" },{ code: "AB", name: "Alberta" },{ code: "BC", name: "British Columbia" },{ code: "MB", name: "Manitoba" },{ code: "NB", name: "New Brunswick" },{ code: "NL", name: "Newfoundland and Labrador" },{ code: "NS", name: "Nova Scotia" },{ code: "NT", name: "Northwest Territories" },{ code: "NU", name: "Nunavut" },
        { code: "ON", name: "Ontario" },{ code: "PE", name: "Prince Edward Island" },{ code: "QC", name: "Quebec" },{ code: "SK", name: "Saskatchewan" }, { code: "YT", name: "Yukon" }
      ]
    };
    
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="selectExample" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <div class="form-group state-surround" ng-class="{'has-error': (newAddressForm.state.$dirty || isPageSubmitted) && newAddressForm.state.$error.required}" ng-if="(address.countryCode == 'CA' || address.countryCode == 'IN' || address.countryCode == 'US')">
    <label for="address-primary-input-state">State</label>
    <select required name="state" id="address-primary-input-state" size="1"
            class="form-control" name="state" ng-model="address.stateCode"
            ng-options="s.code as s.name disable when !s.code for s in states[address.countryCode]">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```